# Cocos2d Forcefully Ending Touch

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, collision-detection

Is there a way to call upon the ccTouchEnd method?

Like, in my update, I want it write

```
If(situation occurs){
[self ccTouchEnd];
}
```

Or something like that. The reason I'm asking is because this thing happens for 2 different reason. one would be if the user ends the touch. The other would be if the sprite collides with another sprite.

Comment: why you want same touch method? just copy functionality and make new function...Call that function from 2 different case..one from touchesEnded and when collides..

Comment: It doesn't work like that though Raj.


I have this sprite that will grow when I touch it. I want the sprite to stop growing either after I end the touch or if the ball hits another sprite.

Comment: I think I got something.

Here's what I'm thinking putting in the update function.

       
    if (sprite stopActionByTag:1) {
        [self addNewSprite];
        [self removeChild:redBall cleanup:YES];
    }
Can someone help me make that work?